# Passing params from cakePHP to file outside of application

Tags: cakephp

I have to modify application written in very old version cakePHP (1.1 I think). 
In certain place application refers to "alien" PHP file (I mean outside of the application). Author did it like this:

```
$response->a_file="/alien_file.php?param1=value1&param2=value2";
```

As you can see _GET is used. My goal is to improve security and use _SESSION to pass parameters. The problem is that in "alien" file there are no params which I put into session. I tried:

```
$this->Session->write('param1', 'value1');
```

and

```
$_SESSION['param1'] = 'value1';
```

Inside the controller values are visible, in "alien" file they are not.

Comment: How is the session being initialized in the `alien.php`? Things like the session name will need to match between the two.

Comment: In `alien.php` I use `session_start()`. I'm new in PHP, what do you mean by session name?

Comment: Yes! Good clue. Default session name is `PHPSESSID`, in cakePHP is `CAKEPHP`. So, in my code first I have to use `session_name('CAKEPHP');` and then `session_start();`

Comment: Did that resolve it?

Comment: Absolutely. I owe you a beer.